# Is It Possible to Make Elbow Pasta At Home?

Tags: pasta

I love making egg, semolina, and wheat pasta at home, but my home pasta maker (a KitchenAid attachment with a roller and two cutter blades) does only basic fettucini and spaghetti shapes plus whatever I cut the sheets to myself.  Is it possible using either a by-hand technique or another machine to make elbow pasta or other round shapes at home, or is this something I have to stick to buying?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to buy a pasta plate that will get you what you need.
The link is not a recommendation, just am example of what you are looking for.

[Pasta plate for KitchenAid mixer](https://www.google.com/search?q=pasta%20plate%20kitchenaid%20mixer&tbm=shop)

Comment: I googled like crazy for this for asking here and somehow missed this - probably because I was looking at the KitchenAid pasta roller sets and not the grinder attachment.  So many attachments...

Comment: I know, the world of home pasta is a little confusing to get into, but well worth the effort once you get the basics down.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw a machine for elbow macaroni called "pasta perfetto 900". May be foreign but was definitely making elbows

Comment: Welcome! Note that this site has users from all over the world so describing something as "foreign" is meaningless: any item you could mention is "foreign" to probably most people here.